# How to scroll without clicking window to focus in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a file navigate window (b) and a edit window (a). I want to scan the `window-b` with scrolling, while I'm editing a file in the `window-a`.

So I `set mouse=a`, and I have to focus the cursor in `window-b`. But I wish not to focus it, how to?

[image: example]

Comment: May want to look at: [Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to do what you want.
What if you had another window-c, how would you know which window to scroll !?

Just use :h window-move-cursor with :h scrolling for the window that is in focus, or if you're more comfortable with a mouse, use that instead.